# writing Yaml file in python with no new line

Tags: python, file, io, yaml, pyyaml

Let's say I have the following snippet :

```
import yaml
Key = ["STAGE0", "STAGE1"]
dict = {}
dict[Key[0]] = [' ']
dict[Key[1]] = [' ']
dict[Key[0]][0]="HEY" 
dict[Key[0]][0]="WHY newline?"
with open("SUMMARY.YAML", "w") as file_yaml:
    yaml.dump(dict, file_yaml)
```

The output `SUMMARY.YAML` file looks like this :

```
STAGE0:
- WHY newline?
STAGE1:
- ' '
```

However I need to save them, in the following desired format :

```
STAGE0: WHY newline?
STAGE1: ' '
```

I am unable to get this output

Comment: each STAGE you've written contains a _list_, not a single value, so even controlling the print format would (should) wrap them in `[]`

Comment: Can you please provide a code block ?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a much more complex structure than you need, full of lists and references, just create the dict directly if you can

```py
data = {
    "STAGE0": "value0",    # single value
    "STAGE1": ["value1"],  # value in list
}
```

```py
>>> print(yaml.dump(data))
STAGE0: value0
STAGE1:
- value1
```

or if you're amending in possible steps, just add the keys and values directly

```py
data = {}

if True:
    data["STAGE0"] = "value0"
if True:
    data["STAGE1"] = "value1"
```

Finally, if you do create lists, `.append()` is likely a much better choice to add values rather than trying to create all the indicies initially

```py
try:
    data[key].append(value)
except KeyError:
    data[key] = [value]
```

Comment: `print(yaml.dump(data))` is inefficient both for time and memory. Just do `yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)` if you want to dump to stdout.

Comment: @Anthon oh, perhaps, though they intend to write a normal file stream directly, so this is just for example (where with such a trivial case, importing `sys` likely takes longer!) .. still, I think far it's more important to hint to the idea that very green to expert programmers can debug and explore programs using humble features like `print()`, `type()`, `help()`, and `dir()`, and should do so to understand intermediate state and available features

Comment: I have had to help non-novice programmers who ran out of memory because of this, and I don't think it is a good idea to create sub-par programming habits that can easily be avoided by providing bad examples to a novice or expert. You also don't explain the use of `if True` in your second example or why you use the four lines in your last example instead of the availabe feature `data.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` that replaces those four lines. You might help solve the immediate problem the OP has, but you are moving them in the wrong direction wrt becoming a better programmer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your program that you should be aware of:

- `dict` is a reserved keyword in Python. You should not mask it by using it as a variable name. With that that keyword you can make an empty dictionary `data = dict()` or
  initialize one, with some restrictions to the keys: `data = dict(a=42, hello='world')`
- Your `dict[Key[0]] = [' ']` set the value of `dict['STAGE0']` to a list with one element, the string with one space,
  then `dict[Key[0]][0]="HEY"` overwrites this string with one space with "HEY" and the following code line
  overwrites that with "WHY newline". You could directly do `dict[Key[0]] = ['WHY newline?']

A minor thing to think about is being consistent with using single or double quotes around strings, and not use both (triple quotes can be different, and  usually triple double quotes are used)

As for the desired output, that is a YAML document with a root level mapping that consists of keys and values that
are all scalars. Mappings are loaded from YAML as dictionaries (unless tagged in YAML, but you don't have that). Scalars
are loaded as strings, or if they are recognised as such, as booleans, integers, floats, datetime.datetime, or datetime.date
instances.

You are using PyYAML which I cannot recommend for new developments, as it only supports a subset of YAML 1.1 wich was outdated back in 2009. I recommend using `ruamel.yaml` in the example (disclaimer: I am the author of that YAML 1.2 library), but the techniques
of getting a solution to your problem are the same.

First load your expected output and inspect the data structure you get loading your desired output. With PyYAML:

```py
import yaml

yaml_str = """\
STAGE0: WHY newline?
STAGE1: ' '
"""
    
data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'STAGE0': 'WHY newline?', 'STAGE1': ' '}
```

Same code using `ruamel.yaml`:

```py
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
STAGE0: WHY newline?
STAGE1: ' '
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

which also gives:

```
{'STAGE0': 'WHY newline?', 'STAGE1': ' '}
```

As you can see the data structure you get consists of a Python `dict`, with strings as keys and strings as values. There
are no lists, so you should not use them if you start building up the datastructure from scratch. PyYAML:

```py
import sys
import yaml

Key = ['STAGE0', 'STAGE1']

data = {}
data[Key[0]] = 'Why newline?'
data[Key[1]] = ' '
    
with open("SUMMARY.YAML", "w") as file_yaml:
    yaml.dump(data, file_yaml)

print(open('SUMMARY.YAML').read())
```

which gives your desired output:

```
STAGE0: Why newline?
STAGE1: ' '
```

With `ruamel.yaml` I recommend using a `pathlib.Path` instance, which gets correctly opened to handle non-ASCII scalars
by default:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml


path = Path('SUMMARY.YAML')
Key = ['STAGE0', 'STAGE1']

data = {}
data[Key[0]] = 'Why newline?'
data[Key[1]] = ' '

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, path)

print(path.read_text())
```

giving:

```
STAGE0: Why newline?
STAGE1: ' '
```

If you continue to use PyYAML, please be aware that values like `12:34:56` will be loaded as integer (converted
from sexagesimals) and `On`, `Off`, `Yes`, `No` as booleans although those "features" were written out of
the YAML specfication fourteen years ago.

Comment: just an extra highlight for the final _here be dragons_ note and the suite of unexpected/frustrating/hilarious type conversions available to 1.1 parsing!

Comment: this is an amazing summary for future readers with yaml -python related questions